# making text fade in when I hover over an image or link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get some text to that is in a `<p>` tag when I hover over a certain image. I can not get the text to show and the code seems to look good to me. Can anyone help me find out why the text is not showing/

here is the HTML

```
<div class="iconcontainerhover">
        <a rel="left" href="#"><img style="margin-right: 160px;" src="img/facebookicon.png" /></a>
        <a rel="middle" href="#"><img src="img/Twittericon.png" /></a>
        <a rel="right" href="#"><img style="margin-left: 160px" src="img/google_plus_icon.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="descripinfo">
        <div id="lefticoncontent">
            <p id="left">This is information about the left icon</p>
        </div>
        <div id="middleiconcontent">
            <p id="middle">This is information about the middle icon</p>
        </div>
        <div id="righticoncontent">
            <p id="right">This is information about the right icon</p>
        </div>
```

and here is the jquery

```
$(function(){
     $('.iconcontainerhover a').mouseenter()(function(){
         var toShow = '#' + $(this).attr('rel');
         $('#discripinfo').show();
         $(toShow).show();
     }).mouseleave(function(){
         $('#discripinfo').hide();
     });
});
```

so I am trying to get the text in `#discripinfo` to fade in when the matching img from `iconcontainerhover` is hovered over.

btw the `#discripinfo` tags are set to `display: none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few typos in your JavaScript.  Here's what you should write.

```
$(function(){
    $('.iconcontainerhover a').mouseenter(function(){   
        var toShow = '#' + $(this).attr('rel') +'iconcontent';
        $('#descripinfo').show();
        $(toShow).show();
     }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#descripinfo').hide();
     });
});
```

**Changes #1) `descripinfo` instead of `discripinfo` #2) add 'iconcontent' after left/right.**  The reason I added the iconcontent is that you probably actually want to hide/show the entire outerwrapper instead of the inner wrapper.  Visually, it will probably look more correct when you have styling applied.

I still don't think it's doing what you expected because you're showing the left/right center.  You should really hide and show those when you do #descripinfo.  To get the feel you want, add this one hide to your mouseenter.

```
        var toShow = '#' + $(this).attr('rel') +'iconcontent';
        $('#descripinfo').show();
        $('#descripinfo div').hide();
        $(toShow).show();
```

[Here's the final jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8bctf/)

Comment: if i have them fade in and then fade out, i see a glimpse of the previous one fading away. is there any way to stop this?

Comment: please look above at the comment

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `()` after `mouseenter` that shouldn't be there. Other than that, it looks okay, although you should probably look into [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

EDIT: Also, make sure you hide the comment that was opened too, otherwise you'll end up with all the descriptions showing up at once.

Comment: unfortunately when i removed the unneeded () it still did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#descripinfo').fadeIn();`

From the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: that is nicer looking thank you. but i still can not get the <p> tags to show in the first place

Comment: You've got a typo. That should be descripinfo.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ewazej/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){
     $('.iconcontainerhover a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){

         $('#descripinfo > div').hide();       
         if(e.type=='mouseenter') $( '#'+this.rel+'iconcontent' ).show().siblings().hide();

     });
});
```